# proportion of the voters/ Central limit theorem

Tags: real-analysis, probability, random-variables, central-limit-theorem

I want to compute the proportion of the voters p. Therefore I consider random variables $X_k$ for $k=1,...,n$:
 $$
     X_k=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} 1, party \ is \ elected: "p" \\
         0, party \ is \ not \ elected: "1-p" \end{array}\right. 
 $$
I can approximate $p$ by $p'_n= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n X_k $
Now I want to calculate the number of voters n, so that $$ P(|p'_n-p| \leq 0,02) \geq 0,95$$ holds
As a hint I should use $p(1-p)\leq \frac{1}{4}$ How can I get to this inequality and how can I compute this using central limit theorem?

Comment: It's really not clear. First, there are not enough political party to use Central limit theorem, but what is the precise statement, because nothing of what you wrote makes sense.

Comment: "How can I get to this inequality" - Observe that $f(p)=p(1-p)\implies f'(p)=1-2p=0$ has a maximum at $p=\frac12$ so that $p(1-p)\le\frac12\left(1-\frac12\right)=\frac14$.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire: Now I see that, but how do you get to $ f(p)=p(1-p)$ How can I use this?

Comment: @user659895: The central limit theorem is wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that the central limit theorem tells us that $p_n'$ can be approximated like a normal random variable with mean $p$ and some variance.

> Can you compute what the variance is?

Let $\sigma_n^2$ denote the variance---and thus $\sigma_n$ the standard deviation; then the variable $$\frac{p_n' - p}{\sigma_n}$$ is close to a standard normal.

> Knowing that $(p_n' - p)/\sigma_n$ is roughly a standard normal, how can you examine the probability $P(|p_n' - p| \leq .02)$?

Comment: I would say: $E[x]= n \cdot p$ That means: $ \sigma_n^2= n \cdot ( E[x^2] - n^2 p^2) = n (n p - n^2p^2)$ Is this right?

Comment: It looks like you've got a pit of an error there, it should be $n(E[x^2] - E[X]^2) = np(1 - p)$.  Now that you have the variance, can you do the second piece?

Comment: It is $P( |p'_n-p|\leq0,02)= P( \frac{-0,02}{\sigma \sqrt{n} }\leq \frac{p'_n-p}{\sigma \sqrt{n}} \leq\frac{0,02}{\sigma \sqrt{n}}) = $

Comment: Ok I think that is wrong: $E[X]= \mu=np$ The limit theorem has the form: $P(\frac{\bar{x} - \mu}{\sigma/ \sqrt{n}} \leq a)$

Comment: Maybe it is simler like: $ P(\frac{-0,02}{\sigma_n} \leq \frac{p'_n -p}{\sigma_n} \leq \frac{0,02}{\sigma_n} ) = \Phi(\frac{0,02}{\sigma_n} )- \Phi(\frac{-0,02}{\sigma_n} )$

Comment: Is this the right way?

Comment: Yes, that's the correct way forward.

Comment: Then I have $2 \Phi(0,02 /  \sigma_n) \geq 1,95 $

Comment: $ \sigma_n \leq n/4$ but my left side is smaller then?

Comment: I would get: $ \Phi (0,08/n)=1,96$

Comment: This can' be true?